How can I use stdin with assert_cmd to do integration testing
So, I have a simple CLI app it takes one argument -f (or --file) and then prompt a user to enter: yes to continue and anything else to stop execution (basically exit code 1). I write an integration test using assert_cmd and I am stuck.
I know how to pass arguments to the binary, but I cannot send reply to the prompt yes.
Here is my code:
use predicates::prelude::*;
use assert_cmd::Command;

#[test]
fn add_test() -> Result<(), Box<dyn std::error::Error>> {
    let mut cmd = Command::cargo_bin("hund")
        .expect("Binary hund exists");
    cmd.args(&["-f", "file.txt"]);
    // the code below I tried, but it did not work as I expected..
    // cmd.write_stdin("yes\n");
    cmd.assert().success().stdout(predicate::str::contains("File modified"));
}

When I run the test cargo test I get prompt and I need to enter yes manually.
I have 2 questions:

How to wait/check the prompt?
How actually can I send yes to the prompt?

Thanks in advance!

assert_cmd's documentation says: "Other crates that might be useful in testing command line programs ... rexpect for testing interactive programs."

Can't reproduce. It works fine for me. Can you include the binary?
